# How to fetch a value of a span class in python

Tags: python, selenium

How to fetch the value of the span 'results-count' using python? 
73123

Where the value is dynamic and need to pass this value inside a for loop .

I have used the below command , but this throws AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' error.

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'results-coun')]")

for i in range(1, int(elem.text), 1000):
    ...
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It should be `for ele in elem: print ele.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get a list, you should iterate on each one of the items and there you should able to use the text.

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'results-coun')]")

for item in elem:
    print (item.text)
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that you need a single field instead of multiple.

You should use `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath`

```
span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'results-coun')]").text
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply.. How do i store the value of that span class 'result-count' into a variable.. In this example it would be 73123.

Comment: Thanks , that helped :)